# What does it mean if I can't find a kernel date?

Tags: rooting, kernel

I want to root my ZTE Grand X Max and it asks if the kernel date is before or after a specific date but when I go and look is has no date by the kernel version (3.4.0). What does that mean? Or do I need to look somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

On Android the Kernel Version is displayed within "Settings | Device". In the details you should also find the date of the build.